# VSCode snippet regex for extracting directory and replacing slashes?

Tags: regex, regexp-replace, vscode-snippets

I'm struggling to find a VSCode transformation regex that allows me take a string like this:
`MyProject.Api/Data/RandomPath/Entities/User.ts`
and produce:
`MyProject.Api.Data.RandomPath.Entities`

I can get this working in two passes; one to remove the last slash and filename, and another to replace the slashes with dots. Unfortunately VSCode snippets don't allow chaining, and I haven't been able to figure out how to combine these two passes into one.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got it! It's not pretty; but here it is as follows:

`/[\\/\\\\]\\w+\\.\\w+$|(\\w+)(?:[\\/\\\\]\\w+\\.\\w+$)|(\\w+(\\.\\w+)?)|\\.|[\\/\\\\]/${2}${2:+.}${1}/g`